# SQL Query Optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I need to optimize my queries.For that purpose I am using  Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

My question is can I check the performance of only one SQL query at a time or more than one suing new session?

Comment: You should also get your hands dirty with SQL Profiler - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: But what I am asking is that.... can I check the performance of only one SQL query at a time or more than one suing new session?

Comment: But what I am asking is that.... can I check the performance of only one SQL query at a time or more than one using new session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyze one query at a time right click it in the SSMS script window and choose the option "Analyze Query in DTA" For this workload select the option "keep all existing PDS" to avoid loads of `drop` recommendations for indexes not used by the query under examination.

To do more than one first capture a trace file with a representative workload sample then you can analyse that with the DTA.

Comment: but how to capture a trace file with trace file with a representive workload sample?

Answer (score 0):

**There are simple steps that must follow when writes  SQL Query:-**

1-Take the name of the columns in the select query instead of *

2-Avoid sub queries

3-Avoid to use operator IN operator

4-Use having as a filter in in Group By

5-Don not save image in database instead of this save the image
   Path in database Ex: saving image in the DB takes large space and each
   time needs to serialization when saving or retrieving images in the database.

6-Each table should have a primary key

7-Each table should have a minimum of one clustered index

8-Each table should have an appropriate amount of non-clustered index Non-clustered index should be created on columns of table based on query which is running

9-Following priority orders should be followed when any index is
created  a) WHERE clause, b) JOIN clause, c) ORDER BY clause, d)SELECT clause

10-Do not to use Views or replace views with original source table

11-Triggers should not be used if possible, incorporate
   the logic of trigger in stored procedure

12-Remove any adhoc queries and use Stored Procedure instead

13-Check if there is atleast 30% HHD is empty it will be improves the performance a bit

14-If possible move the logic of UDF to SP as well

15-Remove any unnecessary joins from the table

16-If there is cursor used in a query, see if there is any other way to avoid the use of this
   (either by SELECT … INTO or INSERT … INTO, etc)